# How do i get the new html content and its ID to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue with detecting and using id within replaceWith or new HTML code

Hi, I'm having an issue with replaceWith. When I click on the div below
and replace the HTML. I am not able to use the id within the new div.
I even tried HTML instead of replaceWith and I am still not able to.

```
<div id="action"></div>

<script>
$("#action").click(function(){
var foo = $(this).attr('id');
//$("#"+foo).html("<div id="next">do this</div>");
$("#"+foo).replaceWith("<div id="next">do this</div>");
});
$("#next").click(function(){
var bar = $(this).attr('id');
alert(bar);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to bind it with static element i.e :`$(document).on('click', '#next', function() {..`

Comment: The fact that your code ihas a syntax error is probably getting in the way of things too...

Comment: @Swati correct because your #next id is not present in page load time so the click event can't bind to the #next element

Comment: @Ben.S No, it's posible, you can check my answer below.

Comment: @Phong its not possible your code differ from the question code. you registered the  click event to #next element in the #action click function so only in that function the binding of the click event is happening and in that moment the #next element exist

Comment: Pls, kindly read my answer with 2 cases, bro ^^! @Ben.S

Comment: in the first case registration happening only after the  the #next  element exist in dom.
in second case you append the click event to document element that always exist

Comment: thanks @swati i understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code has `error syntax`, So I divided it into 2 possible cases:

1. Replace HTML then `listen` the event click sequentially.

```js
$("#action").click(function(){
  var foo = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#"+foo).replaceWith("<div id='next'>do this</div>");
  
  $("#next").click(function(){
     var bar = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(bar);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action" >action </div>
```

2. In case you `listen` event on separately, you should use `$(document).on("click","#next", function(){`

```js
$("#action").click(function(){
  var foo = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#"+foo).replaceWith("<div id='next'>do this</div>");
});

$(document).on("click","#next", function(){
   var bar = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(bar);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action" >action </div>
```

Comment: Yes, this was a great help. I tried it and it work. Can you explain why i had to add "on.("click, id,..." ?